# jQuery find checkbox status and alert if boxes unchecked using .find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 9 check boxes. Each has a unique ID and name.

I am trying to use jquery `.find` to locate all checkboxes and confirm their status as checked or unchecked. The correct output would be if it finds an unchecked box it should show the alert "unchecked". With the code I have below, no matter how many are checked or unchecked then it still will show an alert box with "hello." In other words I think this is all having no affect.

Question1: what needs to be added or changed in order for this to actually perform a search for unchecked boxes in my one page form?

Question 2: if I wanted to have the jquery alert not only alert me if there are unchecked boxes but tell me which box of the 9 was unchecked, what do I need to add?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     // on form submit
    jQuery("#user_price_accept").on('submit', function() {
        // to each unchecked checkbox
      var test =  jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)');
    if(test){alert("unchecked");}
    })
})

   <form id="user_price_accept" onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="checkbox" id="balance_due" name="balance_due" value="1">
  <button type="submit">Accept</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Post the complete code (I don't see any "hello" alert) and the HTML as well.

Comment: @louysPatriceBessette I have updated above with the form code. I didnt add all nine of the inputs. The issue is that the code above places a checkmark in each of my boxes instead of seeing if they are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code you aren't preventing the default of the form so it will be submitting normally. Also the variable test is an array so there will always be a value so you need to check the length.

And on another note, because you are using query you should just use the jquery submit function

```js
jQuery( "#user_price_accept" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var test =  jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
  if(test.length > 0){alert("unchecked");}
});
```

If you want to then figure out which checkboxes are checked you need to loop over the result of test. Here I am just console logging the names of the inputs that arent checked. You might want to concat them into a string if you want them to appear in your alert

```js
jQuery( "#user_price_accept" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var test =  jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
  test.each((i,element ) => {
    console.log(element.name)
  });
  if(test.length > 0){alert("unchecked");}
});
```

Comment: Actually, `test` would be a jQuery object containing a collection, not an array. The use on the `.on()` handler is prefered compared to the `.submit()`...

Comment: True, but the outcome would still be the same

Comment: `.submit()` is simply a shorthand method for `on('submit'`. Switching one for the other is just personal preference

Comment: @richardhpa thank you very much this fixed my issue and addresses my second question as well with a nice solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // on form submit
  jQuery("#user_price_accept").on('submit', function(e) {
    // to each unchecked checkbox
    var test = jQuery(document).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)');
    console.log(test.length);
    if (test.length) {
      alert("unchecked");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="user_price_accept">
  <input type="checkbox" id="balance_due" name="balance_due" value="1">
  <button type="submit">Accept</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```